# How to position two views on opposite ends with flexDirection?

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
    <View>
        <Input />
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "row"
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
            <Text>Hello!</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
            <Icon
              name="md-send"
              type="ionicon"
            />
          </View>
        </View>
    </View>
```

But this renders the following:

[image: img]

How can I make it so that the Icon is at the right end, and the Text remains at the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this like

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
  <View>
     <Text>Hello!</Text>
  </View>
  <Icon
    name="md-send"
    type="ionicon"
   />
</View>
```